# VBA Excel Line Break in Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I've been searching for a solution to this problem for over a week now.  I have a sheet with formatted text (colors and styling) with values an undetermined distance down the first column.  There are some spaces in between but I believe I've handled that situation correctly by using IsEmpty.  I want to copy each of these values from each cell all to one cell at the top of the second column.  I've been successful in being able to copy the text from each of these cells into a specified concatenated cell with line breaks, however I've been unsuccessful at keeping the formatting.  Any help anyone can provide on how to copy the formatting along with this text would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

```
'set variable to find the last row of the sheet
Dim LastRow As Integer
'find the last row of the active sheet
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'loop through each of the rows
For C = 1 To LastRow
    'determine if a cell has a value in it - if so complete below commands
    If (IsEmpty(Cells(C, 1).Value) = False) Then
    'leave the contents of the first cell in the second column, insert a linebreak and copy the values from the current cell in the first column
    Cells(1, 2).Value = Cells(1, 2).Value & Chr(10) & Cells(C, 1).Value
    End If
Next C
```

Comment: Please see this thread http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showpost.php?p=3034158&postcount=5 Andrew Poulsom has already given a code which does what you want.

Comment: Note though that there's a bug in that code: if your first value to be concatenated has any leading spaces, then the call to `Trim()` after the concatenation loop will put all the following formatting steps off by the number of leading spaces trimmed off...

Comment: Thanks for the link, this accomplishes what I was looking for and more

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of Range.Copy and Range.PasteSpecial properties that is easy to use and solved your problem of formatting cell .

Comment: Yes this would solve the problem of copying and pasting with formatting, however this would not allow me to concatenate the range into one cell.